# Grails - Images located in a different path when running from a war

Tags: grails, vaadin, war

I've been developing an Grails application that uses some FileResources located in this directory:

MyGrailsApplication\web-app\images

I'm able to get this directory through grails naturally through GrailsResourceUtils.WEB_APP_DIR. However, when I convert my Grails project into a .war file and deploy it to a tomcat server, that code does not work - the path gets messed up.

Through some debug statements, I was able to find a hacky work-around to this (essentially, do a code modification right before I make the war):

```
// BELOW 2 LINES WORK IN THE WAR FILE, BUT NOT WITH THE RUN-APP CMD
new FileResource(new File("../webapps/InstanceChecker-0.1/images/ok.png"))
new FileResource(new File("../webapps/InstanceChecker-0.1/images/http404.png"))

// BELOW 2 LINES WORK WITH RUN-APP, BUT NOT IN THE WAR
new FileResource(new File(GrailsResourceUtils.WEB_APP_DIR + "/images/ok.png"))
new FileResource(new File(GrailsResourceUtils.WEB_APP_DIR + "/images/http404.png"))
```

Is there a way to cleanly get the image path both in run-app and also when its deployed as a .war? Are there some best practices that I'm missing out on here?

Edit: Perhaps I'm not putting the images in an ideal directory? I'm open to advice on that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For get a resource file you can use this:

```
   def basePath = grailsApplication.mainContext.servletContext.getRealPath('images')
```

Check if end with "/":

```
basePath = basePath.endsWith("/") ? basePath : basePath + "/"
```

And then:

```
new FileResource(new File(basePath+"fileName"))
```

Remember to inject grailsApplication in your controller/service

Comment: This worked out for me - it gets the right path for both run-app and in a deployed war.

Answer (score 0):

you can (also) utilize grail's linkGenerator like

```
final headerImage = new Image(null, new ExternalResource(Grails.get(LinkGenerator).resource(dir: "images", file: "logo.png")))
```

Comment: I've been trying this out and it doesn't really work. Doing a System.out.println(Grails.get(LinkGenerator).resource(dir: "images", file: "banner.png")); ... yields: "/MyGrailsApplication/images/banner.png". The actual file is found at: MyGrailsApplication\web-app\images\banner.png. I also tried copying the image directory to be right under /MyGrailsApplication just like it seems to want, but no luck.

Comment: @jiman just put the `banner.png` into the `web-app/images` dir and the generated URL from the generator will be the proper one for your war and `run-app` (`/MyGrailsApplication` is your context and `/images/banner.png` is the mapped resource - this adopts with the kind of deployment)